# How to get value of TextBox of GridView in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm little bit confusion, how to get value of TextBox of GridView in RowEditing and I've textchange event and that textbox value need to update via gridview to database. but before updating we need to calculate that value.

In RowUpdating we get value normally but in function calculationA() i'm not getting value of textbox. and need to calculate that value and show edited value in same textbox also.

```
public void calculationA()
{
    TextBox txt_BCICU = (TextBox)grdlist.FindControl("txt_BCICU");
    TextBox txt_BCSupDlx = (TextBox)grdlist.FindControl("txt_BCSupDlx");
    txt_TotalChargeA.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txt_BCSupDlx.Text.Trim()) + Convert.ToDecimal(txt_BCICU.Text.Trim())).ToString(); 

protected void txt_BCICU_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        calculationA();
    }     

protected void grdlist_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt_BCICU = (TextBox)grdlist.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_BCICU");
        TextBox txt_BCSupDlx = (TextBox)grdlist.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_BCSupDlx");
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: You don't need `TextChanged` event to implement your requirement. You  can get the textbox values in `RowUpdating` event and in same event you can do what you are doing in `calculationA` method. Check my answer I have just added for complete details.

Comment: I agree with you @Sunil,
but I've to do calculation of that values and show into other label in gridview.  For that we need to do calculation for the same

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

**APPROACH 1**

You don't need `TextChanged` event to get value of textbox in gridview.

You can get the textbox value in `RowUpdating` event as in code below.

Also, remove the calculationA method and instead use the last line of code I have given in RowUpdating event.

```
protected void grdlist_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string textBox1Text = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_BCICU")).Text;

    string textBox2Text = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_BCSupDlx")).Text;

    //remove the calculationA function and just use the code below in 
    //RowUpdating event
    txt_TotalChargeA.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2Text.Trim()) + Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1Text.Trim())).ToString();
}
```

**APPROACH 2**

If you must have the `TextChanged` event then you can get textbox values as in code snippet below.

I have commented the call to calcualteA method since the same calculation can be done in TextChanged event. Note how the current grid row is obtained by getting the `NamingContainer` property of the textbox that raised the TextChanged event.

**Get Textbox values in TextChanged event**

```
protected void txt_BCICU_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        //find this textbox Text i.e. txt_BCICU Text
        string txtBCICUText = (sender as TextBox).Text;


        //find the current grid row and through it other textboxes text
        GridViewRow currentRow = (sender as TextBox).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        //find textbox txt_BCSupDlx Text
        string txtBCSupDlxText = ((TextBox)currentRow.FindControl("txt_BCSupDlx")).Text;

       //do your calculation here
       txt_TotalChargeA.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtBCSupDlxText.Trim()) + Convert.ToDecimal(txtBCICUText.Trim())).ToString(); 

        //calculationA();
}
```

Comment: sir I need to do calculation because I've more than 10 textboxes values that we have to edit that's why I need to calculate. for that I've to edit textbox in textchange event in gridview but values don't come. it shows only null value and I got NullReferenceExecption for that.

Comment: Can you not get all 10 textboxes in RowUpdating event and do your calculations there?

Comment: I have added another approach where `TextChanged` event is used to get the values of textboxes.  So, you can either use `Approach 1`  without TextChanged event or `Approach 2` with TextChanged event.

Comment: If you have to use `calculateA` method and cannot comment it out, then I can suggest another option. Let me know if you want it and I'll post it.

Comment: Thank You @Sunil. but I did it with GridViewRow and its working fine as I need. So thanks for giving me your precious time.

Comment: Do you need the approach wiht calculateA method?

Comment: No need now. Thanks again

Comment: Please mark this as answer, if it has satisfied your requirement.